# Generating a pem with openssl in C

Tags: c, openssl, bitcoin, pem

I'm working on a key util library, and unfortunately I'm having a little bit of difficulty reliably creating a pem. I successfully create a pem maybe 98% of the time but every now and then I get a bad pem. Any idea what's going on?

I'm compiling with `gcc key_utils.c tests.c -o key_tests -lcrypto -lssl -Wall`

Headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/ripemd.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
```

.

```
int generatePem(char **pem) {

    char *pemholder = calloc(224, sizeof(char));
    EC_KEY *eckey = NULL;

    BIO *out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BUF_MEM *buf = NULL;
    EC_GROUP *group = NULL;

    group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    buf = BUF_MEM_new();
    eckey = EC_KEY_new();

    createNewKey(group, eckey);

    EC_GROUP_clear_free(group);

    PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey(out, eckey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    BIO_get_mem_ptr(out, &buf);

    memcpy(pemholder, buf->data, 223);

    if ( buf->data[219] == '\n') {
        pemholder[220] = '\0';       
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 221);
    } else if ( buf->data[221] == '\n') {
        pemholder[222] = '\0';       
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 223);
    } else {
        pemholder[223] = '\0';
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 224);
    }

    free(pemholder);
    EC_KEY_free(eckey);
    BIO_free_all(out);

    return NOERROR;
};
```

The bad pem looks like so:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHMCAQEEH8kO/hjEyM2hvQk//LSsp1xRBIYNDRjAi4b8N78odyCgBwYFK4EEAAqh
RANCAAQ43017I40ci8YMLJnguD/DHUjohY4blKoJ4lXYbgYqyjWvJfVnsNPMU8H9
o3IdPwAitnJjCOG11n9DIQoS3S/o
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
6T
```

Comment: Have you looked at [**EVP Signing and Verifying**](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by getting a bad pem?  Could you include an example of a good one?

Comment: [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) just copies the values. It does not allocate memory. Is `pem` allocated in the calling function ? The fact that the argument of the function is `char** pem` makes me think that it is not the case.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin! I'll check this out.

Comment: Here's a good pem @Mr.Llama
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEILEofa86L9b5sBtm+xC7QzbgG12Dh9m+xXS2tt5JC7dtoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEIwAi5mHDbS/ayykbAwW+/iSoz599ghFp1z6TzPAmJEE44UH+BZZEiGMG
sAhv6KqKorUEjrIjOaUa4m7PNfjrfA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Notice the MHQCAQ at the beginning. That is one of the indications of a good pem.

Comment: @francis: https://github.com/aleitner/bitpay-c-keyutils/blob/master/tests.c#L97 Of course I'm allocating pem. How would I even work with C if I didn't know what memcpy does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm dumb, and 220 bytes is a valid PEM.

Here's the working code, in case anyone else needs to see it in the future.

```
int generatePem(char **pem) {
    int returnError = NOERROR;
    char * errorMessage = "";
    char *pemholder = calloc(240, sizeof(char));
    EC_KEY *eckey = NULL;
    BIO *out = NULL;

    if ((out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())) == NULL) {
        returnError = ERROR;
        errorMessage = "Error in BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())";
        goto clearVariables;
    }

    BUF_MEM *buf = NULL;
    EC_GROUP *group = NULL;

    if ((group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1)) == NULL) {
        returnError = ERROR;
        errorMessage = "Error in EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1))";
        goto clearVariables;
    }

    if (((eckey = EC_KEY_new()) == NULL) ||
        ((buf = BUF_MEM_new()) == NULL)) {
        returnError = ERROR;
        errorMessage = "Error in EC_KEY_new())";
        goto clearVariables;
    };

    if (createNewKey(group, eckey) == ERROR) {
        returnError = ERROR;
        errorMessage = "createNewKey(group, eckey)";
        goto clearVariables;
    }

    if (PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey(out, eckey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL) == 0) {
        printf("PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey error");
    }

    BIO_get_mem_ptr(out, &buf);

    memcpy(pemholder, buf->data, 224);
    if (buf->data[218] == '\n') {
        pemholder[219] = '\0';
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 220);
    } else if ( buf->data[219] == '\n') {
        pemholder[220] = '\0';       
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 221);
    } else if ( buf->data[221] == '\n') {
        pemholder[222] = '\0';       
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 223);
    } else if (buf->data[222] == '\n') {
        pemholder[223] = '\0';
        memcpy(*pem, pemholder, 224);
    } else {
        returnError = ERROR;
        errorMessage = "invalid PEM generated";
        goto clearVariables;
    }

    goto clearVariables;

clearVariables:
    if (group != NULL)
        EC_GROUP_clear_free(group);
    if (pemholder != NULL) 
        free(pemholder);
    if (eckey != NULL)
        EC_KEY_free(eckey);
    if (out != NULL)
        BIO_free_all(out);
    if (errorMessage[0] != '\0')
        printf("Error: %s\n", errorMessage);

    return returnError;
};

static int createNewKey(EC_GROUP *group, EC_KEY *eckey) {

    int asn1Flag = OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE;
    int form = POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED;

    EC_GROUP_set_asn1_flag(group, asn1Flag);
    EC_GROUP_set_point_conversion_form(group, form);
    int setGroupError = EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, group);

    int resultFromKeyGen = EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);

    if (resultFromKeyGen != 1 || setGroupError != 1){
        return ERROR;
    }

    return NOERROR;
}
```